# What else can you do if the inspect element doesnt work?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriver

I have been trying to get an account balance text to print in python using selenium. I go to chrome, inspect the element, copy the xpath, put it in VS and it says cant find the xpath. I did the same thing for CSS selector, full xpath, tried to create my own xpath, tried by class name, etc. Ive tried every option it has. nothing is working. What do you do when you run into this situation? It is there on the website, its gotta be accessible in the background somewhere. The has to be a way to grab it. I have been able to get other text on the site to display properly.

This is just a stock simulator game, I have it open to the public if you want to log in and try your hand at getting the correct inspect element.

[image]

The xpath it generates:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span
```

How I have it in VS:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span')
```

The error in VS:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the amount `Net Worth` Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and  following `xpath`.

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[./span[text()='Net Worth']]/following::span[1]"))).text)
```

OR

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='list list--kv']/li[1]/span"))).text)
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```